# Set entity reference field in form to readonly

Tags: entities

I am building a custom module to set default values for entity reference fields. To avoid overwriting these defaults, i would like to set the field readonly. While I got the defaults to work, setting it readonly does not work, the field is still editable. Here is my code :

```
function prepopulate_references_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'producttype')
  $result = $query->execute();
  $refobject_ids = array_keys($result['node']);
  // the next line works great:
  $form['field_testreference'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = $refobject_ids;
  // this line doesn't have any effect:
  $form['field_testreference'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#attributes']['readonly'] = TRUE;
  // ... and this one neither:
  $form['field_testreference'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
```

What is the problem here?

Edited:
As Darvanen suggested, `dpm()` shows that `$form['field_testreference']['#access'] = FALSE;` works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you're referencing a language where it isn't necessary, try one of these:

```
$form['field_testreference']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

or

```
$form['field_testreference']['#attributes']['readonly'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Your code does not work neither ... maybe the problem is a wrong nested array?

Comment: Have you checked dpm($form) to see if you've got the arrays right?  Mine usually have [0] in place of [LANGUAGE_NONE]...

Comment: Actually they don't have that key at all, edited answer